# WPF: Can't binding to Dependency Property in User Control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

Why I can't bind to the Dependency Property in my UserControl?
I only see the String "Test" as the default value but the binding does not run in a test application. if i do the same binding in the test application in a textblock object than it works. so the problem must be in the myItem class with the dependencyproperty.

**Code:**

```
public partial class myItem : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(String), typeof(myItem), new UIPropertyMetadata("Test"));

    public myItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public String Header
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged("Header");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mixed everything here, try creating Dependency property using propdp and show us what are you trying to bind

Comment: Are there any binding exceptions in the output window? You also don't actually NEED to raise INotifyPropertyChanged if you're using a dependency property but I guess you may have your own reasons for that.

Comment: Please thoroughly read this artice: [Custom Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The dependency property already handles notifying of changes so you don't explicitly have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
So you can remove the `OnPropertyChanged("Header");` from the setter

If you wanted to call a function on the change of this property the correct way is to define it in the Dependency property:

```
 public static DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(String), typeof(myItem), new PropertyMetadata("Test", OnHeaderChanged));

    public String Header
        {
            get
            {
                return (String)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
            }
        }

    private void OnHeaderChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e){ //do something}
```