# Use Dependency Property in code behind

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

How can I use a defined DependencyProperty in my CodeBehind?

This is my DependencyProperty:

```
    ItemContainerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemContainer",
                      typeof(ObservableCollection<Item>), typeof(Manager));
    }


    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemContainer
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Item>)GetValue(ItemContainerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemContainerProperty, value); }
    }
```

When I do that:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ItemContainer.Count - 1; i++)
{
}
```

I get the following errormessage: Inner Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I use the Property in my code?

Comment: did you initialize the ItemContainer? is it bound to some UI element? what does the debugger say?

Comment: @makc how must I initialize the ItemContainer? The property is not bound to an UI element. Debugger says that in the for loop the ItemContainer is null

Comment: then you have the unswer why you cant use it, your property should have data/ be initialized the data should represent some business logic

Comment: ok thats the problem for the error. Do you know a good example how can i do a binding to this dependencyproperty? so that i can use: <mycontrol ItemContainer="{Binding myData}">

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to define a default value for the DependencyProperty then you need to have it set at some point, it's default value is null.

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MainWindow));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }
    }
```

if you don't want to do that then you can define the default value on the dependency property declaration.

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>()));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that defaulting a reference type to non-null in a DP like in your second example can introduce very odd bugs as WPF tries to share the single collection between all users of the property (e.g. derived classes) The first example is preferable in most cases.

Comment: I'd even say the second example is invalid in all but very exceptional cases. You should usually *never* do that.

Comment: @Clemens do you have a hint for me why i can't notice when the dependencyproperty of typ observablecollection<> is updatet by a binding? Is there something to implement on the propertychange event?

Comment: You have to register a PropertyChangedCallback with the PropertyMetadata, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15087062/1136211) to your previous question. I strongly recommend reading the article about [Custom Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx).

Comment: If you're wanting to know when something is inserted or removed from the collection then you'll need to subscribe to it's CollectionChanged event.